# Dynamic values in a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have a Google Sheets where I am using this query to pull data from another sheet:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("**SHEETLOCATION**","Master Customer!A1:u10000"),"Select Col3 Where (Col18='Survey Complete' and Col19='Installation Booked')")
```

Is it possible to change the values it is searching dynamically so `Survey Complete` would reference to a cell value, for example:

`Where (Col18='**Value of E3**')`

so I can have the Values in a drop down within E3 and the formula would change with the result?

I have tried to use the INDIRECT function but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SHEETLOCATION","Master Customer!A1:u10000"),"Select Col3 Where Col18='"&E3&"' and Col19='Installation Booked' ")
```